# R vector subtraction

Tags: r

I'm in R and want to subtract two vectors term by term.

Here are my code

```
y <- faithful
u_old1 <- c(3.5,80)

#  eruptions waiting
#1     3.600      79
#2     1.800      54
#3     3.333      74
# ...

y - u_old1

#    eruptions waiting
#1       0.100    75.5
#2     -78.200   -26.0
#3      -0.167    70.5
# ...
```

I think it's the recycling in R that does is. I want each row of `y` minus `u_old1`. So I should get the first row as:

```
#    eruptions waiting
#1       0.100      -1
```

Comment: `u_old1` should be a `list`. Use `y - as.list(u_old1)` instead.

Comment: `y[] <- Map('-', y, u_old1)`

Answer (score 2):

This is what `sweep` was made for:

```
sweep(y, 2, u_old1)

#    eruptions waiting
#1       0.100      -1
#2      -1.700     -26
#3      -0.167      -6
# ...
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you should use `as.list(u_old1)` instead:

Example:

```
head(y) - as.list(u_old1)
#   eruptions waiting
# 1     0.100      -1
# 2    -1.700     -26
# 3    -0.167      -6
# 4    -1.217     -18
# 5     1.033       5
# 6    -0.617     -25
```